# Vertex-transitive, finite case

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a graph all of whose vertex-deleted subgraphs are isomorphic. Show that $G$ is vertex-transitive.

I've already seen a proof on this page, but it wasn't complete. Could you please help me?

Comment: Do you have a link to the incomplete proof you saw?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065012/vertex-transitive-graphs-and-deletion-of-vertices

Comment: there are some things they assume obvious, for me it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this fill in all the holes.  They aren't very deep.

Suppose $G$ has $m$ edges. Since $G\setminus u$ is isomorphic to $G\setminus v$, they have the same number of edges, and $G\setminus u$ has $m-\deg_G(u)$ edges, and $G\setminus v$ has $m-\deg_G(v)$ edges.  Thus $G$ is regular, as claimed.

Say $G$ is $k$-regular.  Let $f$ be an isomorphism from $G\setminus u$ to $G\setminus v$.  Since the neighbors of $u$ in $G$ are of degree $k-1$ in $G\setminus u$, $f$ must map them to the neighbors of $v$ in $g$.  Now define a map $g$ from $G$ to $G$ by $$g(x)=\cases{f(x),&$x\ne u$\\v,&$x=u$}$$

We must show that $x,y$ are adjacent in $G$ if and only if $g(x),g(y)$ are adjacent in $G$.  If neither $x$ nor $y$ is $u$, then this is true because $g$ extends $f$.  If $x$ or $y$ equals $u$, then this follows from the remark that $f$ maps neighbors of $u$ to neighbors of $v$.

For the reverse implication, apply the same argument to $g^{-1}.$

Comment: I have a doubt, it is not possible for the graph to admit loops?

Comment: I assumed the question related to simple graphs.  Offhand, I don't know what happens if you allow loops.

Comment: Ok, for the simple case it is correct, I would like to know what happens in the most general case, do the definitions made to the subject allow the existence of loops?

Comment: @PedroAlejandroBestard I'm not sure what happens if you allow loops or multiple (parallel) edges.  I'll think about it.

Comment: well, I´ve been reading now and I realize that the edge-transitive definition was made for simple graphs in the book from where I took the excercise, it is [Bondy & Murty], Graph Theory (Springer 2008)

Comment: thank you very much!!!

Comment: Is there an analogous theorem for finite edge-transitive graphs? Something like: finite $G$ is edge transitive iff for any edge e and f, G−e is isomorphic to G−f?

Comment: @KaragounisZ If you have a different question, please post it as a question, not a comment.